# Toggling Bluetooth on Wingpanel does not toggle Bluetooth in settings

Tags: release-loki, settings, bluetooth

...in Loki.

Has anyone else observed this, is it a reported issue?

I noticed this connecting a Wiimote to Loki the other day... I kept getting 'unable to connect messages' using wminput.

Lo and behold while the indicator was bold and the switch set to the 'on' position in Wingpanel, the same was not true in System Settings.

In summary, System Settings toggles Bluetooth in Wingpanel, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this bug was [just released](https://medium.com/elementaryos/loki-updates-for-the-new-year-ff6b6ba65531#f5d7). Running an update in AppCenter and then restarting should fix the problem.

---

Edit: the fixes for bugs [1607475](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1607475) and [1600520](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1600520) should in theory have fixed the problem, but the issue persists. I'm able to reproduce the problem on my machine. I've asked in one of the tickets whether it would be helpful to file a new ticket or reopen one of the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks. Software is up to date. Checked against Synaptic and wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth is latest version, as is  switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth (assuming these are the offending items). Issue persists.

Comment: The fix doesn't solve everything. When you turn on/off BT from wingpanel it doesn't turn it on/off inside settings.